# Unable to extend mount point using lvextend

Tags: rhel, lvm

Here is the output of lsblk

```
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda                    202:0    0  100G  0 disk
├─xvda1                 202:1    0    1M  0 part
└─xvda2                 202:2    0  100G  0 part /
xvdb                    202:16   0  200G  0 disk
├─xvdb1                 202:17   0   24G  0 part [SWAP]
├─xvdb2                 202:18   0   40G  0 part
│ ├─rootrhel-varlog     253:0    0   20G  0 lvm  /var/log
│ └─rootrhel-storetmp   253:1    0   20G  0 lvm  /storetmp
└─xvdb3                 202:19   0  136G  0 part
  ├─storerhel-store     253:2    0 28.8G  0 lvm  /store
  └─storerhel-transient 253:3    0  7.2G  0 lvm  /transient
```

As you can see the /xvdb/xvdb3 has 136G. What I need is to increase the storerhel-store to 100G.

However, when I issued, lvextend, I got the following insufficient free space error:

```
[root@ec ~]# lvextend -L 100G /dev/mapper/storerhel-store
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[145336]) leaked on lvextend invocation. Parent PID 11244: -bash
  Insufficient free space: 18228 extents needed, but only 0 available
```

Am I missing something? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards

Comment: Aren't you running this in Midnight Commander, are you?

Comment: What does `lvs` say the sizes of your xvrb3 LVs are? And what does `pvs` say about xvdb3?

Comment: ... and what does `vgs` say about `storerhel`?

Comment: Is `storerhel-store` using contiguous allocation?